# Dell XPS 12 Duo with 16 or 32 gigs of ram?

Tags: memory, dell-xps

The Dell XPS 12 Duo has two SO-DIMM slots (at least according to the dell tech i talked to).  Dell only lists up to 8 gigs of ram supported, but does anyone out there know whether or not I could use a pair of 8 gig SO-DIMMs or 16 gig SO-DIMMs in that laptop?  (Sort of like how the unibody macbook pros officially only supported 8 gigs of ram, but you could toss a pair of 8 gig so-dimms in them and get 16 gigs of ram).

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Unfortunately that model only supports 8GB. (I've tried.)